# UICollectionView autosize and dynamic number of rows

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, rows, screen-rotation, autosize

I am trying to do something like this:

[image]
Basically, I am using a `UICollectionView` and the cells (3 diferent `.xib`).

So far, it works.

The thing I want to do is:

1. Set a `autoheight`
2. If rotate, add 1 row to the `UIColectionView`
   2.1 If tablet, on portrait will have 2 rows and landscape 3 rows. (which basically is the same of point 2, only adding 1 row.

I have something like this:

```
extension ViewController {
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator){
    setSizeSize()
}

func setSizeSize(){
    if(DeviceType.IS_IPAD || UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeLeft || UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeRight){
        if let layout = myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
            layout.invalidateLayout()
        }
    }else{
        if let layout = myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize
            layout.invalidateLayout()
        }
    }
    myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
}
```

Does not work. Also, it freezes device. On simulator works parcially. (I'm trusting more device)

I also tried [this](https://medium.com/@wasinwiwongsak/uicollectionview-with-autosizing-cell-using-autolayout-in-ios-9-10-84ab5cdf35a2), but it works sometimes...

Please, let me know if you need more info.

Thank you all in advance for the help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can suggest you to create your own `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` subclass which would generate needed layout. Here is a simple flow layout that you can use. You can adjust it to your needs, if I missed something.

```
public protocol CollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate: class {
    func numberOfColumns() -> Int
    func height(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
}

public class CollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    private var cache: [IndexPath : UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = [:]
    private var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0
    private var contentWidth: CGFloat {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
            return 0
        }
        let insets = collectionView.contentInset
        return collectionView.bounds.width - (insets.left + insets.right)
    }

    public weak var flowDelegate: CollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate?

    public override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: self.contentWidth, height: self.contentHeight)
    }

    public override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        var layoutAttributesArray = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
        if cache.isEmpty {
            self.prepare()
        }
        for (_, layoutAttributes) in self.cache {
            if rect.intersects(layoutAttributes.frame) {
                layoutAttributesArray.append(layoutAttributes)
            }
        }
        return layoutAttributesArray
    }

    public override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        return self.cache[indexPath]
    }

    public override func prepare() {
        guard let collectionView = self.collectionView else {
            return
        }
        let numberOfColumns = self.flowDelegate?.numberOfColumns() ?? 1
        let cellPadding: CGFloat = 8
        self.contentHeight = 0
        let columnWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / CGFloat(numberOfColumns)
        var xOffset = [CGFloat]()
        for column in 0 ..< numberOfColumns {
            xOffset.append(CGFloat(column) * columnWidth)
        }
        var column = 0
        var yOffset = [CGFloat](repeating: 0, count: numberOfColumns)

        for item in 0 ..< collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)
            let photoHeight = self.flowDelegate?.height(at: indexPath) ?? 1
            let height = cellPadding * 2 + photoHeight
            let frame = CGRect(x: xOffset[column], y: yOffset[column], width: columnWidth, height: height)
            let insetFrame = frame.insetBy(dx: cellPadding, dy: cellPadding)
            let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
            attributes.frame = insetFrame
            self.cache[indexPath] = attributes
            self.contentHeight = max(self.contentHeight, frame.maxY)
            yOffset[column] = yOffset[column] + height
            column = column < (numberOfColumns - 1) ? (column + 1) : 0
        }
    }
}
```

Now in your UIViewController you can use it like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let flowLayout = CollectionViewFlowLayout()
    flowLayout.flowDelegate = self
    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout
}
```

invalidate `collectionView` layout after orientation would be changed

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    guard let flowLayout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? CollectionViewFlowLayout else {
        return
    }
    flowLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

and now make your `ViewController` conform to `CollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate`

```
extension ViewController: CollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate {
    func height(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        guard let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) else {
            return 1
        }
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        //get calculated cell height
        return cell.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
    }

    func numberOfColumns() -> Int {
        //how much columns would be shown, depends on orientation
        return UIDevice.current.orientation == .portrait ? 2 : 3
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, although you might want to explain what each line of your code does

Comment: Good Answer! I'll give it a try.

Comment: Works great! Exactly what I wanted! Thank you. The only thing is... what if I want the smallers cells to be centered of the bigger ones? Like on the image...

Comment: Centered horizontally and vertically, is that possible?

Comment: @Amg91 yes, it's possible. You need to adjust code inside `prepare()` method. In  `for in` loop we setting frames for cells. You need to calculate correct `y` for each cell

Comment: I've been trying to do it... havent found a soulution for that. Algo, no make the cell widther only. Which means: centered vertically (smaller cells), width of all cells: screenSize/n. I will give you the bounty.

Comment: @Taras Chernyshenko, I have tried but nothing works. I want to set cells' with to collectionView.width/numColumns but does not work. Also, if possible, centered on yAxis... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Amg91 show me what you have did so far, and I will try to help you

Comment: I tried setting width=collectionView.bounds.width/numColumns-(numColumns)*cellPadding. I tried also with sizeAtIndex but changes everything. I am lost about how and where...

Comment: It worked now, but 1 of the 3 cells is not responding for the size change... I do not know what could it be...

Comment: @Amg91 post code that you have right now and I will try to help you

Comment: I do not have that much code... I am using what you did. The thing is that only on one cell is not doing what it is supposed to. Literally, I have your code, but it is not affecting the size on 1 cell type. Do you want me to post the .xib? (How do I?) Or which code do you want me to paste? UIViewController? Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: Got no clue what it was on that xib. I redid everything on that cell and I think I removed a safe area and worked. I think that was. Sorry for that much trouble and thank you again.

Comment: The think that I am having now is, when I reload the data (collectionView.reloadData(), the cells' height is 1, because of the height method... How do I make it work when I reload data?

Comment: That heightAt function literally saved the rest of my hair turning gray.  THANK YOU!!

Comment: Works great for the visible cells, however when I scroll all the cells has a height of 1, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This could be another alternative:

```
protocol MyLayoutDelegate: class {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, heightForCellAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath, width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat
    func numberOfColumns() -> Int
}

import UIKit

class MyCollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {

    weak var delegate: MyLayoutDelegate!


    public var cellPadding: CGFloat = 5.0

    var cellWidth: CGFloat = 190.0
    var cachedWidth: CGFloat = 0.0
    var minimumInteritemSpacing: CGFloat = 10

    var numberOfColumns = 1

    fileprivate var cache = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
    fileprivate var contentHeight: CGFloat  = 0.0
    fileprivate var contentWidth: CGFloat {
        if let collectionView = collectionView {
            let insets = collectionView.contentInset
            return collectionView.bounds.width - (insets.left + insets.right)
        }
        return 0
    }

    fileprivate var numberOfItems = 0

    override public var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
    }

    override func prepare() {

        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return }

        self.numberOfColumns = delegate.numberOfColumns()

        cellWidth = (contentWidth - minimumInteritemSpacing * 2) / CGFloat(numberOfColumns)

        let totalSpaceWidth = contentWidth - CGFloat(numberOfColumns) * cellWidth
        let horizontalPadding = totalSpaceWidth / CGFloat(numberOfColumns + 1)
        let numberOfItems = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
        if (contentWidth != cachedWidth || self.numberOfItems != numberOfItems) {
            cache = []
            contentHeight = 0
            self.numberOfItems = numberOfItems
        }

        cachedWidth = contentWidth
        var xOffset = [CGFloat]()
        for column in 0 ..< numberOfColumns {
            xOffset.append(CGFloat(column) * cellWidth + CGFloat(column + 1) * horizontalPadding)
        }
        var column = 0
        var yOffset = [CGFloat](repeating: 0, count: numberOfColumns)
        for row in 0 ..< numberOfItems {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)
            let cellHeight = delegate.collectionView(collectionView, heightForCellAtIndexPath: indexPath, width: cellWidth)
            let height = cellPadding * 2 +  cellHeight
            let frame = CGRect(x: xOffset[column], y: yOffset[column], width: cellWidth, height: height)
            let insetFrame = frame.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: cellPadding)
            let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath as IndexPath)
            attributes.frame = insetFrame
            cache.append(attributes)
            contentHeight = max(contentHeight, frame.maxY)
            yOffset[column] = yOffset[column] + height
            if column >= (numberOfColumns - 1) {
                column = 0
            } else {
                column = column + 1
            }
        }
}

override public func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    var layoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
    for attributes in cache {
        if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
            layoutAttributes.append(attributes)
        }
    }
    return layoutAttributes
}

override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    return cache[indexPath.item]
}

}
```

To use this:

***1)*** In the storyboard select your collectionView ( Es. myCollectionView ) and search for CollectionViewLayout
***2)*** Click on the class inspector and change the class to MyCollectionViewLayout.

***3)*** In your viewDidLoad:

```
if let layout = myCollectionView?.collectionViewLayout as MyCollectionViewLayout {
        layout.delegate = self
    }
```

***4)*** Add the two protocol stubs:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, heightForCellAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath, width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    //default height for different layout
    guard let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? MyCollectionViewLayout else{return 150 // or anything else}

    //return what you want, even based on screen size
    return 100

}

func numberOfColumns() -> Int{
   //return number of columns based on screen size

   return 1 // or whatever you want
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Sorry for asking, but what's the difference between yours and @Taras Chernyshenko's solution?